# When website content overflows, Cant scroll up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, overflow

Not really much else to say, other than the code. I just cant scroll up when the resolution is small enough, stuff overflows, and i cant view that stuff. Although i can scroll down

I used JavaScript allot because its a game. Its way to extensive to post but if you really want it tell me

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas">You're browser does not support the canvas tag. Go and get a real browser, nub</canvas>
    <div id="redSelector">
        <div class="genericButton" id="zombieRed">Zombie</div>
        <div class="genericButton" id="skeletonRed">Skeleton</div>
         <div class="genericButton" id="creeperRed">Creeper</div>
        <div class="genericButton" id="spideBlue">Spider</div>
    </div>
    <div id="blueSelector">
        <div class="genericButton" id="zombieBlue">Zombie</div>
        <div class="genericButton" id="skeletonBlue">Skeleton</div>
         <div class="genericButton" id="creeperBlue">Creeper</div>
        <div class="genericButton" id="spiderBlue">Spider</div>
    </div>
    <div id="options">

        <div class="lineContainer">
            <div class="heading" id="Options-heading">Insert Title Here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="lineContainer">
            <div class="text" id="Options-info">Welcome to Insert Title Here. This game is a strategic game with an scaled up<br>
                                                rock paper scissors concept. To beat you're opponent, You must select certain<br> 
                                                mobs that do good against you're opponents mobs. You can also make combinations<br> 
                                                of mobs to destroy you're opponents base but you must take into consideration <br>
                                                the prices. better mobs require more money and take up more population.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="lineContainer">
            <div id="Restart" class="options-button">Restart</div>
            <div id="Exit" class="options-button">Exit</div>
            <div id="Play" class="options-button">Play</div>
        </div>
        <div class="lineContainer">        
            <div id="Credits" class="options-button">Credits</div>
            <div id="Support" class="options-button">Contact</div>
            <div id="Controls" class="options-button">Controls</div>
        </div>
        <div class="lineContainer">
            <div id="CreditsInfo" class="options-tab">Made entirely by _____ ____</div>
            <div id="SupportInfo" class = "options-tab">Please tell me what you think and how I could improve. (Link)</div>
            <div id="ControlsInfo" class="options-tab">A-D to move player 1 scrollbar. J-L to move player 2 scrollbar. Hover over mob to see stats. Press O to pause.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="rectangle.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-horizontal;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
}

html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);  
}
#Options-info{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px;

}

#redSelector{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0px auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid black
}
#blueSelector{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px ;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0px auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.genericButton{ 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50;
    height: 75;
    margin: 10;
    border: 2px solid black
}
#canvas{
    border: 10px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
#options{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 650px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.options-button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid black;

}
.options-tab{
    display: none;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 153, 255)
}
.options-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(155, 103, 0)
}
.options-button:active{
    position: relative;
    top: 1;
}

.heading{
    font-size: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px 25px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.lineContainer{

}
```

Comment: Off topic but, css should get loaded in the head.

Comment: Try getting rid of height 100%. I've had issues where overflowed content with calling a 100% height caused an issue. Since scrolling is a defacto thing in the web, calling height 100% isn't really necessary because you're probably going to use more than 100% of the height window on mobile. Also try overflow-y: hidden; in your body tag and see if it cuts content away. If it doesn't it might help. But I think the fault lies in the height: 100%

Answer (score 0):

You have positioned your elements using absolute.
To fix the main container which has the ID of "options" and contains the options buttons.

Change:
    #options {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 80%;
     height: 650px;
     border: 10px solid black;
     background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
     margin: auto;
     text-align: center;
    }

to:
    #options {
     position: relative;
     width: 80%;
     height: 650px;
     border: 10px solid black;
     background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
    }

I would also recommend you change the height property of #options to auto so the size of the container expands.

You will most probably need to change the way other elements are positioned to stop overlapping.